# Check if StateStore is fully populated

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a compact topic with approx 30Mio Keys.
My `App` materializes this topic to a `KeyValueStore`.

How can I check if the `KeyValueStore` is completely populated? If I lookup a key via `InteractiveQuery` I need to know if the key is not present because the `StateStore` is not ready yet or if the key is indeed not present.

I materialize the StateStore this way:

```java
  @Bean
  public Consumer<KTable<Key, Value>> process() {
    return stream -> stream.filter((k, v) -> v != null,
        Materialized.<Key, Value, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("stateStore")
            .withKeySerde(new KeySerde())
            .withValueSerde(new ValueSerde()));
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there is no such thing as "fully loaded" because after the application was started at any point in time new data might be written to the input topic and this new data would be read to update the corresponding table.

What you can do is to monitor consumer lag: within you application `KafkaStreams#metrics()` allow you to access all client (ie, consumer/producer) and Kafka Streams metrics. The consumer exposes a metric called `records-lag-max` that may help.

Of course, during normal processing (assuming that new data is written to the input topic all the time) consumer lag will go up-and-down all the time.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated** : I misunderstood OP's question from "how to check if the Topology has finished materialized the input topic to state store" to "state store restore process"

You can only get KeyValueStore from your KafkaStreams instance when the KafkaStreams' state has changed from `REBALANCING` to `RUNNING` state.
You can check this this state transition using a `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer` to access the underlying KafkaStreams instance.
If you just want to check when all state store have been fully populated and when kafka stream thread is ready so you can get a `KeyValueStore` the you can listen on `StateListener`:

```
@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer onKafkaStateChangeFromRebalanceToRunning() {
    return factoryBean -> factoryBean.setStateListener((newState, oldState) -> {
        if (newState == KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING && oldState == KafkaStreams.State.REBALANCING) {
            // set flag that `stateStore` store of current KafkaStreams has been fully restore
            // then you can get
        }
    }
}
```

or if you want to get the store from `KafkaStreams` instance

```
@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer streamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer() {
    return factoryBean -> factoryBean.setKafkaStreamsCustomizer((KafkaStreamsCustomizer) kafkaStreams -> {
        kafkaStreams.setStateListener((newState, oldState) -> {
            if (newState == KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING && oldState == KafkaStreams.State.REBALANCING) {
                //get and assign your store using kafkaStreams.store("stateStore", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
                //and set flag that `stateStore` store of current KafkaStreams has been fully restore
            }
        });
    });
}
```

[Read more in the docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_streamsbuilderfactorybean_customizer).

Note that there should be only one instance of StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer.

Comment: My observation is that although the state of the stream is already `RUNNING` there are still elements _flowing in_ the StateStore.

Comment: `flowing in` do you mean that stateStore is still restoring? how do you check this?

Comment: Seem I misunderstand you , I thought you ask about restore process, will update the answer

Comment: I added the `stateStore#approximateNumEntries` to a custom `HealthIndicator` and this number is still increasing although the overall `/health` is already `UP`.

Comment: For the provided program on initial startup there is nothing to be restored -- the application will start processing with an empty state -- for the given program, processing _mean_ writing into the store...